# 何から何までちょっとはずれたヤツでして・・・

Tags: sentence

The main character (桐生) gets a request of the owner of an 揚屋 (we're talking Edo period here) to get rid of a guy squatting in front of said store, not bulging for days. As the MC beats up the guy, he learns that the guy wanted to buy one of the girls and hoped he could convince the owner by not giving in until he got what he wanted.
Afterwards the owner thanks the MC and this is the conversation:

> 店員「ありがとうございました」
> 桐生「で、こいつが姫雀か。」*姫雀 is the name of the girl
> 店員「はい、そうなんです」
> 桐生「・・・ふぅ、まだ禿じゃないか」*禿 is defined here as a 遊女 of the lowest rank
> 店員「えぇ、**何から何までちょっとはずれたヤツでして**・・・本当に助かりました」

The bolded part is where I'm lost and I really don't know what the sentence is trying to say here. I understand 何から何まで means something like すべて、みんな、一から十まで and is seen in phrases like 何から何までありがとうございます or 何から何までお世話になりました but I can't really place its usage here. Furthermore, I don't know who ヤツ is refering to here, the guy causing trouble or the girl? Also what does はずれたヤツ mean? Or is it ちょっとは ずれたヤツ? Still couldn't explain the meaning though.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PRPGjhgVDG8
Here is a video of the scene, with the bit from above starting at 4:36. It's only a few seconds long and it may make things clearer; maybe the formatting of the lines in the dialogue boxes is important? The line in question is formatted like this:

> えぇ、何から何まで
> ちょっとはずれたヤツでして・・・
> 本当に助かりました。

I don't know if this is important or not, but I thought I'd point it out nevertheless.

As usual many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We don't commonly say はずれた奴 at least in modern Japanese, but this はずれた (外れた in kanji) clearly means "out of the way", "eccentric", "peculiar", "lacks common sense", etc. It refers to the guy, not the girl. [常識はずれ(な)](https://jisho.org/word/%E5%B8%B8%E8%AD%98%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9A%E3%82%8C) is a related common expression.

> えぇ、何から何までちょっとはずれたヤツでして…
> Yes, he was a bit peculiar guy in every way...

In the video, the guy is peculiar in several ways:

- Did not know 500文 was not enough to redeem a girl
- Thought squatting silently in front of the building would solve the problem
- Loved a small girl

Actually, ズレた also has a similar slangy meaning (ちょっとズレた奴 = someone who is a bit off), and ズレた奴 is much more common than 外れた奴. But putting a contrastive-*wa* after ちょっと doesn't make sense in this sentence.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Given the flow of the conversation, it seemed a bit off to me to shift the topic from the girl to the guy like that ("Huh, she's still just a kamuro, isn't she." "Yes, that guy was peculiar in every way..."), but that's just me then. I also didn't know that 何から何まで can be used in that fashion. Thanks a lot for the help!